# How to rearrange admin menu

Tags: 7, hooks, navigation

I have made a few admin items for our site and we would like to collapse them into a series of nested menu options.  I've found all our menu items, and changed the path to be nested properly.  I've flushed cache, and some of the menu items get nested, others done.

One thing about this is that the 'root' for menu is in a feature module, and most of the other children for this root are in a custom module.

In an attempt to get this working, on my local instance, I disabled the custom module, which in turn disabled the feature module that holds the root.  After re-enabling the feature module, then the custom module, the menu structure I am looking for appeared.  However, I'm not too keen on disabling/re-enabling modules on a prod site to get an admin menu working.

I also tried going into devel/php and executing `menu_rebuild();`.  There was no change in the menu before or after flushing the cache.

Is there a way to rearrange my admin menu more appropriately?

Comment: How are your menu items defined in your module's hook_menu in regards to their [menu types](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/group/menu_item_types/7.x)?